# Custom type is encoded as Bytes

Tags: rpc, custom-types

In my pallet have created a custom new-type, in the same fashion as `AccountId32`:

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Ord, PartialOrd, Debug, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct GenericId(BoundedVec<u8, MaxGenericIdLenGet>);
```

The type can be converted `From<GenericId> for BoundedVec<u8, MaxGenericIdLenGet>` and `From<BoundedVec<u8, MaxGenericIdLenGet>> for GenericId`.
I would expect it to show up in the [polkadot-js explorer](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer) as `GenericId` (`AccountId32` indeed shows up), but it shows as `Bytes` instead.

How do I make `GenericId` show up not as `Bytes`?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't do this.

The `TypeInfo` will explain this type as `BoundedVec<u8, MaxGenericIdLenGet>`.

So, it shows bytes in the PolkadotApps.

---

Why `H256` work?

In fact, `H256` is `[u8; 32]`.

But PolkadotApps makes some wrap for it.

Then it could be displayed as `0x00...` instead of `[0,...]`.

---

If you want to do this.

IIUC, you've to tweak the PolkadotJS about how it deals with `GenericId`.